# missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 30s - RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using `rabbitmq` for pub/sub. I have two micro-services which communicates each other through `rabbitmq` exchange. micro service1 publishes some data and micro service2 consumes it. The rate of publishing and subscribing is very less, its like 100 times a day. `rabbitmq` randomly throwing the "Missed heartbeats from the client, timeout: 30s".
That's why my application error outs as "**queue shutdown**". Whenever I restart queue, services able to use it and starts working.

I am using docker and node for microservices. and https://www.npmjs.com/package/rabbot npm package for `rabbitmq` implementation.

This is my `rabbitmq config`

```
{
  "connection": {
    "server": [
      "rabbitmq"
    ],
    "port": 5672,
    "vhost": "%2f",
    "timeout": 4000,
    "waitMin": 10000,
    "waitIncrement": 3000
  },
  "exchanges": [
    {
      "name": "save-customer",
      "type": "topic",
      "persistent": true,
      "autoDelete": true
    },
    {
      "name": "poison-ex",
      "type": "direct",
      "persistent": true,
      "durable": true,
      "autoDelete": true
    }
  ],
  "queues": [
    {
      "name": "save-customer-q",
      "autoDelete": true,
      "subscribe": true,
      "deadLetter": "poison-ex"
    },
    {
      "name": "poison-q",
      "noAck": false,
      "autoDelete": false,
      "durable": true,
      "poison": true
    }
  ],
  "bindings": [
    {
      "exchange": "save-customer",
      "target": "save-customer-q",
      "keys": [
        "send-customer-data"
      ]
    },
    {
      "exchange": "poison-ex",
      "target": "poison-q",
      "keys": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the log of rabbitmq server

```
root@ALIPL5126:/opt/hos-customer-service# docker logs opt_rabbitmq_1
2018-05-31 07:09:25.438 [warning] <0.26747.0> closing AMQP connection <0.26747.0> (192.168.16.5:45180 -> 192.168.16.2:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 30s
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [config docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) and [their heartbeats article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) you have two options to try:

1. Disable heartbeat, which *is highly discouraged* (c), but will work for sure.
2. Increase the default heartbeat time in your config, for example to be `3600` (in seconds, which equals to 1 hour)

Comment: Any idea which is there a heartbeat miss happening in the first place.